# Green's function for the Yamabe problem

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, conformal-geometry

I'm currently reading the paper on the Yamabe problem by Lee and Parker, and am looking for a reference for Theorem 2.8.

> **Theorem 2.8** (Existence of the Green Function).
>
> Suppose $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold of dimension $n\ge 3$, and $h$ is a strictly positive smooth function on $M$. For each $P\in M$, there exists a unique smooth function $\Gamma_P$ on $M\setminus \{P\}$, called the **Green function** for $\Delta + h$ at $P$, such that $(\Delta + h)\Gamma_P = \delta_P$ in the distribution sense, where $\delta_P$ is the Dirac measure on $P$.

Does anyone know where I might find out about general existence results for Green's functions (in particular this one)? Thanks!

Comment: Chapter 4 of Aubin's _Nonlinear Analysis on Manifolds_ constructs the Green's function for the Laplacian on a Riemannian manifold (without the $h$).

Comment: @HenryT.Horton: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry we weren't more explicit about giving references.  I haven't come up with a good reference for an explicit proof of our Theorem 2.8; but here are three suggestions for constructing your own proof.

1. Following Henry Horton's suggestion, you can adapt the proof in Aubin's *Nonlinear Analysis on Manifolds* to this case.
2. As Tom Parker and I commented after the proof of Theorem 6.5 in our paper, that proof can be adapted to prove the existence of the Green function, if you've already proved that $\Delta+h$ is an isomorphism between appropriate Sobolev spaces: First you use the procedure in the proof of Theorem 6.5 to construct an approximation to the Green function of the form $\Gamma_0 = r^{2-n}(1+\bar\psi)$; then let $f_0 = (\Delta+h)\Gamma_0$ and note that $f_0$ is in some Sobolev space on which $(\Delta+h)^{-1}$ exists.  The Green function is $\Gamma_P = \Gamma_0 - (\Delta + h)^{-1}(f_0)$.
3. Or you can use the [Schwarz kernel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_kernel_theorem) to observe that $(\Delta+h)^{-1}$ has an integral kernel $K$, which is a distribution on $M\times M$.  Elliptic regularity shows that it is smooth on the complement of the diagonal.  The Green function is $\Gamma_P(Q) = K(P,Q)$.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: =) How cool is this! Thank you very much for these suggestions (and for writing the paper, I guess).