# Generalized stereographic projection

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a closed (compact, without boundary) Riemannian manifold and let $p\in M$. Let 
$$
\square: =c\Delta+S
$$
be the *conformal Laplacian* of $(M,g)$. Here $c=4\frac{n-1}{n-2}$ is a constant, $\Delta$ is the Laplacian and $S$ is the scalar curvature defined by $g$. Lastly, let $G_p:M\setminus \{p\}\to \mathbb{R}$ be the Green function of $\square$, so $\square\, G_p=0$ everywhere on $M\setminus \{p\}$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306109/greens-function-for-the-yamabe-problem?rq=1) for a discussion of the conformal Laplacian $\square$ and its Green function $G_p$.

If $(M,g)$ has positive scalar curvature, then the *generalized stereographic projection* of $(M,g)$ is defined to be the Riemannian manifold $(\hat{M},\hat{g})$, where 
$$
\hat{M}=M\setminus \{p\} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \hat{g}=G_p^{k-2}g,
$$
and $k=2n/(n-2)$ is a constant. This is well defined when $(M,g)$ has positive scalar curvature, since in this case the Green function $G_p$ is strictly positive.

**Question 1:** If $n\geq 4$, is the Riemannian metric $\hat{g}$ on $\hat{M}$ complete?

I suspect this is the case as [Lee and Parker](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183553962) prove that metric $\hat{g}$ is asymptotically flat of order at least 2.

My second question is related to the curvature properties of $(\hat{M},\hat{g})$. Note that $(\hat{M},\hat{g})$ has zero scalar curvature, as follows from the fact that $\square\, G_p=0$.

**Question 2:** How is the Ricci curvature of $\hat{g}$ related to the Ricci curvature of $g$? More specifically, if $g$ has Ricci curvature bounded above or below, does this give bounds on the Ricci curvature of $\hat{g}$?

Comment: A naive question : is classical stereographic projection from the sphere minus one of its pole to a plane really a particular case of what you explain ?

Comment: You can establish an asymptotic estimate for $G_p$ near $p,$ which in particular lets you bound it from below by $r^k$ for some constant $k(n).$  (You should definitely be able to find this in Lee-Parker.) You can then verify completeness of the metric by using this bound to show that the length of any curve approaching $p$ is infinite.

Comment: @JeanMarie: this is explained very nicely in Section 6 of Lee and Parker's paper (see hyperlink in my question).